# Validate if my checkbox is selected or not and save its status in real time

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox that if I select it, my container is hidden and if I deselect it, the container is shown again.

I'm trying to save the state in localstorage. So if the page refreshes or changes, the checkbox maintains its state

Sorry if I don't explain myself well, how could I achieve this? Thank you
My code so far

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myToggle">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<div id="main-container">
    HELLO
</div>

<script>
    const checkbox = document.getElementById('myToggle')
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
            const a = localStorage.setItem('my_variable', 'activated');
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem('my_variable');
        }
    })

    function hideshowContainer(){
        if( a == 'activated'){
            document.getElementById('main-container').style.display="none";
        }else{
           document.getElementById('main-container').style.display="block"; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So what doesn't work? What's your question?

Comment: `localStorage.setItem()` doesn't return anything, what is the `a` variable for?

Comment: And the `a` variable is local to the event listener function, you can't use it in `hideShowContainer()`.

Comment: Use `localStorage.getItem('my_variable')` to get the value you saved. Or use a global variable for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code**

[https://jsfiddle.net/f92awop1/]

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myToggle">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<div id="main-container">
    HELLO
</div>

<script>
    const checkbox = document.getElementById('myToggle');
    
    // Load the checkbox state from localStorage on page load
    const savedState = localStorage.getItem('my_variable');
    if (savedState === 'activated') {
        checkbox.checked = true;
        hideshowContainer();
    }

    checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
            localStorage.setItem('my_variable', 'activated');
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem('my_variable');
        }
        hideshowContainer();
    })

    function hideshowContainer() {
        const currentState = localStorage.getItem('my_variable');
        if (currentState === 'activated') {
            document.getElementById('main-container').style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('main-container').style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Dev Kraken thanks this works for me. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your code is most of the way there. You just need to also read the state of the localStorage value when the page next loads, like this:

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector('#myToggle');
const container = document.querySelector('#main-container');
const hideShowContainer = toggle => {
    container.style.display = toggle ? 'block' : 'none';
}

// set state when the box is checked
checkbox.addEventListener('change', e => {  
  hideShowContainer(e.target.checked);
  localStorage.setItem('toggle', e.target.checked);
});

// set state when the page loads
const toggleStateOnLoad = localStorage.getItem('toggle') == 'true';
hideShowContainer(toggleStateOnLoad);
checkbox.checked = toggleStateOnLoad;
```

Here's a full working example in [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/39p8q0cf/), as SO snippets are sandboxed and cannot access localStorage.